# MySQL Editions Price and WAMP Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wamp

I am using WAMP server.Now I need a desktop application using MySQL database.I checked MySQL website and saw that MySQL prices $2000  for standard edition.So MySQL is definitely not a free product.The how we get MySQL without any cost with WAMP ?.Or is there any difference between MySQL coming  with wamp and the paid ones.?

Comment: MySQL is definitely a free product; the question is whether you are permitted to distribute it yourself. One solution to this is simply not to distribute it. Instead, ask your customers to install MySQL themselves first, and then to run your own installer - if you run your installer as administrator, you can bump MySQL into no-password mode, create your own user account, and then restart it in standard mode - thus the user doesn't even need to supply database passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two edition available , for more detail you can see http://www.mysql.com/products/

**MySQL Community Edition** [MySQL Community Edition is the freely downloadable version of the world's most popular open source database.]

- Learn more about the MySQL Community Edition
- Download the MySQL Community Edition

**Commercial customers** [Commercial customers have the flexibility of choosing from multiple editions to meet specific business and technical requirements]

- MySQL Standard Edition
- MySQL Enterprise Edition
- MySQL Cluster Carrier Grade Edition

Comment: and whether i can get an embeddable version of this community edition,that can be embedded in to my application ?

Comment: @sirajkhan ,plz make clear...if we use mysql for Commercial use then it's not free of cost

Comment: I need to embed a MySQL database inside a desktop application

Comment: You can find the plan on both URL.
http://www.mysql.com/products/
http://www.mysql.com/oem/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [MariaDB](http://mariadb.org). MariaDB is a drop-in replacement for MySQL build by some of the MySQL Devs. There also [PHP-Stacks](http://wpn-xm.org/) available using mariaDB instead of MySQL.